# Using different child views in @each directive with the same parent layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Blade templates in Laravel 5.3. I want to render two lists - one of 'friends' and one of 'acquaintances'. The header and footer of the list is the same in both cases, but items rendered in the friends list have different formatting and fields from those rendered in the acquaintances list.

Here are two methods in my controller:

```
public function showFriends() {
  return view('reports.friends', ['profiles' => $friends]);
}

public function showAcquaintances() {
  return view('reports.acquaintances', ['profiles' => $acquaintances']);
}
```

Here are my blade templates:

```
// reports/acquaintances.blade.php
<div>Some generic header HTML</div>
<div class="container">
    @each('reports.acquaintance', $profiles, 'profile')
</div>
<div>Some generic footer HTML</div>

// reports/acquaintance.blade.php
<div class="media">
  <div>Some HTML formatting specific to acquaintance item</div>
  {{ $profile->name }}
  {{ $profile->job }}
</div>

// reports/friends.blade.php
<div>Some generic header HTML</div>
<div class="container">
    @each('reports.friend', $profile, 'profile')
</div>
<div>Some generic footer HTML</div>

// reports/friend.blade.php
<div class="media">
  <div>Some HTML formatting specific to friend item</div>
  {{ $profile->name }}
  {{ $profile->birthday }}    
</div>
```

This doesn't seem to be a very efficient way to achieve what I want because the I've had to create two identical parent templates for my lists: friends.blade.php and acquaintances.blade.php. What I really need is the ability to have a generic parent template and then somehow to specify in my controller which template I want to use to render the list items. Is this possible? Is there another, more elegant way to implement this? I'm just starting to get my head around Blade and any pointers would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could break it into a generic `persons_list` and two custom items. Then use a conditional inside of the list:

```
public function showFriends() {
  return view('reports.persons_list', ['profiles' => $friends, 'type' => 'friends']);
}

public function showAcquaintances() {
  return view('reports.persons_list', ['profiles' => $acquaintances, 'type' => 'acquaintances']);
}
```

And blade:

```
// reports/persons_list.blade.php
<div>Some generic header HTML</div>
<div class="container">

    @if ($type == 'friends')

        @each('reports.friend', $profiles, 'profile')

    @else

        @each('reports.acquaintance', $profiles, 'profile')

    @endif

</div>
<div>Some generic footer HTML</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @serg-chernata. This makes perfect sense. I'd had some vague idea that I might be able to reference the child template I wanted to use directly within the call to view(), but if a conditional is the most elegant way to do it, so be it.

Comment: You're very welcome. Please accept the answer whenever you get a chance. :)